# How to prevent pop up alert when receiving push notification and the app is in the foreground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I'm making an IOS chatting app using Swift.
When a user has sent a new message all other users receive a push notification.
The push notification is working well when the user is not using the app, but when the user is using the app and chatting with other users he receives a pop up alert with every message sent by the other users.
I would like to prevent this pop up alert from happening.

This is the code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
// MARK: - DELEGATES FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.current()
        installation?.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
        installation?.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("DEVICE TOKEN REGISTERED!")
            } else {
                print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }})
}
    
 
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
}
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    PFPush.handle(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == .inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(inBackground: userInfo, block: nil)
    }
}
```

And this is the code I wrote in the view controller

```
let pushStr = "\(PFUser.current()![USER_FULLNAME]!): \(m["body"]!)"
                                let data = [ "badge" : "Increment",
                                            "alert" : pushStr]
                                let request = [
                                            "someKey" : id,
                                            "data" : data
                                ] as [String : Any]
                                PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "push", withParameters: request as [String : Any], block: { (results, error) in
                                    if error == nil {
                                        print ("\(pushStr)\n")
                                    } else {
                                        print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                }})
```

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: I edited the question and put the code in the right format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if You are using `UNUserNotificationCenter`

add this method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    if itIsChatAlert { //check by push userInfo
        completionHandler([])
    } else {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use this function. Is there any other suggestion please?

Comment: You should use it if you want make it work, time to implement UNUserNotificationCenter for U